# how do I write javascript to redirect on a home page, if screen.width <=480, only once, upon it's first encounter by a mobile device

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I have created a redirect based on screen width.

The page is  https://galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst.com/home

I would like the redirect to only happen once, when the mobile phone first encounters “home” here:  https://galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst.com/home

I am redirecting the “home” page to a page  called “about-us-mobile” designed for 480 or less screen width using this javascript:

```
if (screen.width <= 480) {
    document.location = "about-us-mobile ";
}
```

I only have 2 pages that are optimized for the 480 or less and a link “shop”on those two pages  which go back to galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst

I want the mobile phone to click the “shop” button to see the full “home” page without being redirected again to “about-us-mobile”.

So I created a page which is a copy of the “home” page and called it “home_full_site_shop”.  It has no redirect on it.  The “shop” button on the mobile pages links to this page.

If the mobile phone eventually tries to link back to the home page again via the “shop” button on any page of galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst  I would like it ***Not*** to redirect again to “about-us-mobile”.

In short,  I would like the redirect to only happen once, when the mobile phone first encounters the galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst home page

Answer (score 1):

If you're tying yourself to **just** JavaScript, your best bet is probably to use a GET variable that is set once your site recognizes the dimensions. This variable being set would indicate to each page that the relevant links should go to the mobile-optimized pages (you could dynamically create the links based on the existence [or not] of this GET var). You could actually avoid both redirects this way. Just pass the GET variable around on each click within your site (this can be done by dynamically modifying all page links onload).

If you also have server-side options (PHP maybe), you have a prettier option. You could use a session/cookie to store whether the current user is mobile or not and send the web browser appropriate links after the session is set.

Comment: Great idea. I am a JavaScript novice, but this sounds like a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, by setting a (in legal terms: technical) cookie (that contains no unique information).

The cookie-option is pretty cross-browser supported and well-documented (unless users turned them of, which is quite the rage at the moment due to awareness-tools like collusion). In that case there a 'problem' for the user if you do not have some fall-back mechanism or graceful degradation.
Should you also depend on javascript, then there are 2 requirements to your site:cookies and javascript.
So although javascript/cookie route is easy to implement, in the long run it does not hurt to look a little further:

Or you could dive into local web-storage with all it's current quirks

And you could log it on your server with a database based on IP or something like that.

Yet another option would be (if you render the html serverside anyway) to rewrite/change all links (using GET variables) in the document and scripts...
Or .htaccess mod-rewrite..?

I'm on a roll...
You could also use 2 sub-domains: Catch the user at the front-door, redirecting them to your resolution/app-specific subdomain, and do this using the javascript-function history.replace(); This way the user cannot navigate back in the history to the 'front-door', hence he is trapped ultimately to the root of the subdomain.

Tada :P

So the proper long-term solution to this requirement starts with making a choice..

Comment: WOW.  I like the history replace, I haven't heard of that.  I definitely need to read up on my javascript.  Started out as purely a "designer" of web pages and find myself always being pulled by more then my brain can handle.  If I can trap the user into going to the "copy" of the home page instead of going to the actual home page, this would be great.  The script evades me perhaps I will spend countless hours trying to learn to write this!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Microsoft IE<10 uses [replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while IE>9, firefox and?? use [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history).    Just don't forget to accept AN answer eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
    window.location = "https://galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst.com/home";
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help.  Unless I am missing something, this is what I want to avoid. https://galleryofjewels.businesscatalyst.com/home has a redirect on it that forces the mobile device to never be able to see this page.